# How to merge local branch with migrations created in docker

Tags: django, docker

In my pet project I set up docker-compose for development. The issue is that I've create django migration  inside docker and when I want to checkout to main branch and merge commits from sub branch I got an error:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
        apps/users/migrations/0002_auto_20190127_1652.py
```

Then I type `git status` and I can see that that migration file is still untracked. And I cannot return to the previous branch because of the same error.

Comment: this is more a git question than anything else. What do you want to do with the new migration? Keep it? Then commit first, then pull. Or ditch it? Then migrate back first, and force merge.

Comment: @dirkgroten I cannot checkout to the previous branch - because of the same error.

Comment: but what do you want? keep the migration (and other local changes) or ditch it? the answer depends on that.

Comment: @dirkgroten I want to keep migration but add it to commit in sub branch

Comment: you can shelve all local changes using [git stash](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing), checkout the sub branch and re-apply the shelved changes, then commit into sub.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may be related with the issue you have reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54391878/how-to-checkout-branches-if-there-are-files-created-in-docker-image).

If so the solution is the same I gave there on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54392565/6454622).

So the above answer solve the permissions issues that I believe are the cause of your error when trying to use git to merge your branches.

With the permissions issue solved git should now work as expected.