# How to checkout branches if there are files created in docker image?

Tags: django, git, docker

In my pet project I set up docker-compose for development. The issue is that I've create django migration inside dockerimage and created commit. After checkout to main branch I see an error. These files become untracked and I cannot merge sub branch into the main.

`git checkout master`

```
warning: unable to unlink 'apps/app_name/migrations/0001_initial.py': Permission denied
warning: unable to unlink 'apps/app_name/migrations/0002_auto_20190127_1815.py': Permission denied
warning: unable to unlink 'apps/app_name/migrations/__init__.py': Permission denied
Switched to branch 'master'
```

Also I tried to it with sudo. All new files will appear untracked in main branch but no new commits will be added(based on `git log`)

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./compose/Dockerfile.dev
      context: .
    command: /start
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db:db
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6.8-alpine

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apk update \
  # psycopg2 dependencies
  && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
  && apk add postgresql-dev \
  # Pillow dependencies
  && apk add jpeg-dev zlib-dev freetype-dev lcms2-dev openjpeg-dev tiff-dev tk-dev tcl-dev \
  # CFFI dependencies
  && apk add libffi-dev py-cffi \
  # Translations dependencies
  && apk add gettext \
  # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dbshell
  && apk add postgresql-client

RUN mkdir /code

WORKDIR /code

COPY /requirements /code/requirements/

RUN pip install -r requirements/dev.txt

COPY . /code/

COPY ./compose/start /start
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /start
RUN chmod +x /start
```

start.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

set -o errexit
set -o pipefail
set -o nounset


python manage.py migrate
python manage.py runserver_plus 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: please add your dockerfile and docker compose file and if you have any confidential values on it, then you need to replace them with dummy ones.

Comment: @Exadra37 I've added my files

Comment: 1. you have a volume mapping .:/code, yet you copy . to /code . If you need the volume, the latte ris not necessary

Comment: 2. Be aware that in the absence of user definition in docker and -u flag when runing the container, your containerized app runs as root, so whatever it writes to /code will be under root user, and if you need to change something in . on the host, you may run in into permission issue. Not sure this is the cause of your troublles, so posting in comments. Try running docker with option -u ui:gid, where uid  and gid are your host user user id and group is (as returned by `id -un` and `id -gn`

Comment: @ArtemTrunov Thank you. The problem was in `COPY . /code/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.6.8-alpine

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

ARG CONTAINER_USER="python"
ARG CONTAINER_UID="1000"
ARG CONTAINER_GID="1000"
ARG WORKSPACE=/home/"${CONTAINER_USER}"/code

RUN apk update \
  # psycopg2 dependencies
  && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
  && apk add postgresql-dev \
  # Pillow dependencies
  && apk add jpeg-dev zlib-dev freetype-dev lcms2-dev openjpeg-dev tiff-dev tk-dev tcl-dev \
  # CFFI dependencies
  && apk add libffi-dev py-cffi \
  # Translations dependencies
  && apk add gettext \
  # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dbshell
  && apk add postgresql-client && \

  addgroup -g "${CONTAINER_GID}" -S "${CONTAINER_USER}" && \
  adduser -s /bin/ash -u "${CONTAINER_UID}" -G  "${CONTAINER_USER}" -h /home/"${CONTAINER_USER}" -D "${CONTAINER_USER}"

USER "${CONTAINER_USER}"

WORKDIR "${WORKSPACE}"

COPY  ./requirements/dev.txt "${WORKSPACE}"/requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Is bad practice to run whatsoever in a docker container as the root user, just like you wouldn't do it in your computer. I added a user `python` that will have the same `uid` of your computer, assuming your operating system user as the uid `1000` as it is normal in Linux machines. If you are in another OS than this may not work and you will need to find the solution for your specific OS.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./compose/Dockerfile.dev
      context: .
      args:
        CONTAINER_UID: ${UID:-1000}
        CONTAINER_GID: ${GID:-1000}
    command: ./compose/start
    volumes:
      - .:/home/python/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

`links` is deprecated and was replaced by `depends_on`, thus not necessary to use both.

In order to build the container with the same permissions of your filesystem for your user I have added `args` to de dockerfile build section and I use the OS values for `$UID`  and `$GID`, but if they are not set will default to `1000`.

You can see what are the ones in your Linux OS with `id -u` for `$UID` and `id -g` for the `$GID`.

**Shell Script**

Make it executable in your repo and commit the change so that you don't need to do it each time you build the docker image.

```
chmod 700 ./compose/start
```

> I don't use +x because that is a bad practice in terms of security, once you will allow everyone to execute the script.

**Summary**

Any files created now inside of the container will have the `uid` and `gid` of `1000`, thus no more conflict should occur with permissions.

Comment: Now I have got an error with command `RUN sed -i  's/\r//' "${WORKSPACE}"/start`. It says `sed: can't create temp file '/home/python/code/startXXXXXX': Permission denied`

Comment: I have removed the sed command in the Dockerfile I gave in my answer... What is the reason you have it?